# Regex for email id validation

Tags: java, regex

im new to regexes , I have email validation program with the given conditions for a valid email

`@` and `.` should be present only once

there should be five characters between `@` and `.`

there should be at least 3 characters before `@`

`@` should always precede the `.`

I cannot figure out the last part. Any help with a little explanation would be great :)

Comment: `&` in email address ?

Comment: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/.

Comment: Enjoy!!! http://ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: @sanbhat , where did u see '&' man ? :D

Comment: @Zarin your first post before edit.. SO maintains [Edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22712745/revisions) :D

Comment: that must have been a draft save then... :P

Comment: @sanbhat: Of course `&` can be used in email address, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a standard regex. I generally use

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b.
```

Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for different examples.

Comment: Thing is , im not yet well versed enough to understand what you wrote :P Can you give me a simple regex that will work ? with an explanation if possible ? Thank you :)

Comment: Its a bit complicated to explain it. Your best bet would be to look over that regular-expressions site. Its very good. The first bit says that you can have any word that contains A-z,0-9 and . _ % + - allowed. This must then be followed by an @ followed by another word which contains A-Z0-9.-. followed by . with any characters A-Z

Comment: i understood the basics , i just want a part that checks @ before . conditions

Comment: The last bit has this - @ [any word] followed by a .

Comment: The thing is that most so called "standard regex" for email validation are wrong ;-)

Comment: What about tld like `CONSTRUCTION` or `XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD`. See the official list of tld: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: I know it wont work for all. If you want the full one to meet the RFC 5322 standard you need to use    
  (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
  |  "(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]
      |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")
@ (?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
  |  \[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:
          (?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]
          |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)
     \])

Answer (score 0):

Validating an email using regex is really a tough one and you'll never get satisfied no matter what you use!

Here is the regex that only **based on your four points on the question**. Assuming by any character you mean `[a-zA-Z0-9]`:

```
(?=^[^.@]*@[^.@]*\.[^.@]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\.
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nS6gO6)

Since you'll use is in Java, use `\\` for every `\` in your code.